# Android program type already present

Tags: android, build

I can't seem to resolve this issue. Any solutions for it ?

> Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza

Answer (score 0):

Check exsisting packages base, places and location if one exist. For example you have two packages 'com.google.android.gms'and 'play-services-location' then just remove one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are implementing some similar dependency i.e

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places
```

You should post your `build.gradle (Module:app)` file